# Pip install pycryptodome returns: Is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, pycryptodome

I am trying to install `pycryptodome-3.19.0` and `pycryptodomex-3.19.0` on Windows 11 and Python 3.10 in venv.
Whl files were downloaded from pypi manually:

```
pycryptodome-3.19.0-pp310-pypy310_pp73-win_amd64.whl  

pycryptodomex-3.19.0-pp310-pypy310_pp73-win_amd64.whl
```

Trying to install any of them I have an error:

```
ERROR: pycryptodome(x)-3.19.0-pp310-pypy310_pp73-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform
```

But why? There are most suitable whls availavle on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodomex/#files)
Whls are for windows and for python 3.10. Why it can't be installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've downloaded a [PyPy](https://www.pypy.org/) wheel, but you're trying to install it on CPython.

Look for a wheel tagged with `cp` instead of `pp`.

Run `pip debug -v` to see a list of supported compatibility tags for your Python installation / platform.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about PyPy. Now I see how easy my question is

Comment: @pav No question is easy for those who don't know. I think your question was very valid and I learned something myself. This is also why I upvoted both the answer and your question.

Comment: I have been working with Python for about 20 years. I never noticed that before. That is why real-world experience matters - you get to experience lots of little details.